# What's the easiest way to create CRUD interface for custom entities?

Tags: entities

What is the fastest way to create admin UI for new entity type? Like at content types. I just need basic list/add/edit/delete actions.

One would think this comes with entity api?

I have found a lot of solutions but all of them included a lot of custom code, which is prone to errors.

is DrupalDefaultUIEntityController the answer? how can one use it?

Answer (score 5):

The [Entity Construction Kit (ECK)](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) module allows you to create and manage entities through admin.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ...  builds upon the entity system to create a flexible and extensible data modeling system both with a UI for site builders, and with useful abstractions (classes, plugins, etc) to help developers use entities with ease.
>
> ECK allows the creation and management of entity types with custom properties; adding bundles to entity types; and fields to bundles, with the help of the Field UI module.

Comment: Ram, question was ambigious. Your answer was perfect for one of interpretation (seen in title). Sadly now it looks that the other one was what OP really meant.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api) looks like a manual for exactly what you need. Basically it describes how to use [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module, and extend `EntityAPIController` class to use it's strength but tailor it to your needs.

[Example on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/878804) shows simplest case, without even extending this class, as follows:

> The EntityAPIController automatically provides you with your_entity_type_insert/update/delete/pre_save hooks. If your entity is defined to be fieldable, EntityAPIController invokes the field API attachers for you. You only have to write the API docs yourself. For that you may make use of this API documentation template. Also note that schema fields marked as 'serialized' are automatically unserialized upon loading as well as serialized on saving.
>
> A simple example hook_entity_info() implementation could look like the following:

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_entity_info().
*/
function entity_test_entity_info() {
  return array(
    'entity_test' => array(
      'label' => t('Test Entity'),
      'entity class' => 'Entity',
      'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
      'base table' => 'entity_test',
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'id',
      ),
      // Make use the class' label() and uri() implementation by default.
      'label callback' => 'entity_class_label',
      'uri callback' => 'entity_class_uri',
    ),
  );
}
?>
```

Comment: What about admin UI?

Comment: @gregab it's there, you need hook_menu to access it. It's explained in the article (first link in my answer), and another explanation linked in the docs on Drupal.org (third link in my answer). Sorry, can't really copy-paste complete docs here. Or, see answer by Clive, that's the one I upvoted here.

Answer (score 2):

The [Model Entities](https://drupal.org/project/model) module would probably be an excellent place to start - it contains code to get you started with a custom entity, including the admin interface.

> The objective of this module is to provide a model entity *and* entity administration interface to kick-start your entity development.